# Links to issues from tortosiesvn log to issue tracker (Flyspray)

Tags: tortoisesvn, issue-tracking

We use SVN with TSVN and Flyspray as our issue tracker. The issue tracker itself shouldn't be important from what I've understood from docs.

So I've set up bugtraq:url to:

```
http://our.server.pl/flyspray/index.php?do=details&task_id=%BUGID%
```

And bugtraq:logregex to:

```
[Ff][Ss]#(\d+)
```

Commited and Updated from repo., but only a number is linked in the log messages. Is it possible to have whole sequence linked?

Answer (score -1):

[Issue Numbers Using Regular Expressions chapter](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_sk/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) from docs may help to write good RE
[image]

Note 2 RE - one for message, one for id, and message RE is inside ()

Comment: The regexp already works fine and the link is shown. Only problem is that in "FS#123" only "123" is linked (underlined and blue).

Comment: Nope. Neither /i/ nor (...(...)) doesn't work. TSVN always passes first match and don't escape charcters So passing # doesn't even give you the chance to parse it on server side.

Comment: Quote from docs "bugtraq:logregex. It contains either a single regular expressions, or two regular expressions separated by a newline.

If two expressions are set, then the *first expression* is used as a pre-filter to find **expressions which contain bug IDs**. The *second expression* then extracts the bare bug IDs from the result of the first regex. This allows you to use a list of bug IDs and natural language expressions if you wish."